# HTML Select control behavior

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make an HTML Select control display a different set of strings when clicked (or opened) than what is displayed after an item is selected.  For example, when opened I want to see "one", two", "three" displayed as choices.  But if the user selects two, I want "2" to be displayed as the selected item.  My onclick handler reloads the Select options list with the long version of the strings and the onchange handler repopulates the control with the short strings and then re-selects the selected item.  This works in Firefox, but not in IE, Safari nor Chrome.  It's been almost 10 years since I last had the *pleasure* of coding in JavaScript.  Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```js
var selectedIndex = -1;
function onChanged() {
  //once selected, replace verbose with terse forms
  var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
  selectedIndex = myList.selectedIndex;
  var optionArray = ["One|1", "Two|2", "Three|3"];
  myList.options.length = 0;
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[1];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    myList.options.add(newOption);
  }
  myList.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}

function onClicked() {
  var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
  var optionArray = ["1|One", "2|Two", "3|Three"];
  myList.options.length = 0;
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[1];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1]; 
    myList.options.add(newOption);
  }
  if (selectedIndex > -1)
    myList.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}
```

```html
<select id="myList" onchange="onChanged()" onclick="onClicked()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach would be to have each option store the full version of the text, and only change the displayed text of the selected item to the abbreviated version upon selection.

```js
(function() {
  var valueMap = {
    "1": "One (1)",
    "2": "Two (2)",
    "11": "Eleven (11)",
    "ITAR": "International Traffic in Arms Regulation (ITAR)",
    "ACA": "Affordable Care Act (ACA)",
    "FUBAR": "Fluffed Up Beyond All Recognition (FUBAR)"
  };
  var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
  for (var prop in valueMap) { // populate the dropdown from our object
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = prop;
    opt.text = valueMap[prop];
    myList.add(opt);
  }
  myList.selectedIndex = -1; // nothing selected by default

  myList.addEventListener("change", function() {
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    this.blur();
  });

  myList.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex > -1) {
      var newValue = valueMap[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value];
      if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text !== newValue) {
        this.options[this.selectedIndex].text = newValue;
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<select id="myList" style="width:6em"></select>
```

This gets you most of the way there, but still has the annoying problem that @hopkins-matt alluded to; namely that if the user opens the drop-down list and either selects the already selected item or moves off of the list without selecting anything, the selection will retain the long version of the text.

The other downside to this approach is that you need to specify the select element's width to keep it from expanding to the maximum length of its hidden option elements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  This is almost working for me. with the caveats mentioned above.  I am disabling the selected item, so that re selecting the selected item is a non issue.  Now I'll combine @hopkins-matt latest suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing issue.

<del>Change:</del>

```
<select id="myList" onchange="onChanged()" onclick="onClicked()">
```

<del>to:</del>

```
<select id="myList" onchange="onChanged()" onmousedown="onClicked()">
```

<del>If the user opens the list and moves off the list without clicking, the list will not revert to original unless you call `onChanged()` on `onmouseout` as well.</del>

```
<select id="myList" onchange="onChanged()" onmousedown="onClicked()" onmouseout="onChanged()">
```

---

<del>**Update:** To achieve the best cross browser (onfocus is required for FF, but breaks IE) support without browser sniffing us this combination:</del>

```
<select id="myList" onchange="onChanged()" onblur="onChanged()" onfocus="onClicked()" onmousedown="onClicked()">
```

<del>This will also correct the second selection of the same event, but only after the user clicks away from the element.</del>

---

#### Update:

**Solved**... I think.

I rewrote the function you were using to change the options. IE was not firing `onchange` due to you removing all the `option` elements and adding new `option` elements. Which was causing IE to not be able to reference if the user had changed the selection index. The function now just modifies the value and innerHTML of the current `option` elements. I am using browser sniffing to eliminate the `onmouseout` call for FF. FireFox was calling `onmouseout` if you moved the cursor to the dropdown menu. This does cause a side effect in FF. If the user selects the same option in FF, the options do not return to the original state until the `onblur` is fired.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/3m1syk6c/

**JS:**

```
function changeOptions() {
    var selectedIndex = -1;
    var click = 0;
    var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
    var optionArray = ["One|1", "Two|2", "Three|3"];
    
    var fireFox = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    console.log(fireFox);
    if (fireFox == false) {
        myList.onmouseout=function(){changeList(false)};
    }
    myList.onblur=function(){changeList(false)};
    myList.onchange=function(){changeList(false)};
    myList.onmousedown=function(){changeList(true)};
    
    function changeList(listOpen) {
        var isListOpen = listOpen;

        if (isListOpen == true) {
            for (i = 0; i < myList.options.length; i++) { 
                var pair = optionArray[i].split("|");
                myList.options[i].value = pair[0];
                myList.options[i].innerHTML = pair[0];
            }
        }
        if (isListOpen == false) {
            for (i = 0; i < myList.options.length; i++) { 
                var pair = optionArray[i].split("|");
                myList.options[i].value = pair[1];
                myList.options[i].innerHTML = pair[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
changeOptions();
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="myList">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your suggestion.  For some reason in Firefox, the onChanged method never gets called. Ditto for IE.  Chrome works nicely unless I select the same item again.(onChanged doesn't get called in that case).  Ditto for Safari.  I'll look more closely in a little while.

Comment: I looked a little further into it. Because each browser fires these events differently, the only solution I see right now is to check to see what browser is viewing the page and the bind the events according to the browser.

Comment: @PurpleLagoon Check out the update to my answer for the best solution I can see without browser sniffing.

Comment: Thanks, trying your suggestions now in concert with suggestions from @Thriggle below.

Comment: IE is a problem,  the onChange event doesn't fire!

Comment: Yeah. You'll have to choose between FF and IE, unless you want to do browser sniffing.

Comment: I don't mind browser sniffing but how do I handle IE?  onChange doesn't fire.  Thanks

Comment: @PurpleLagoon this update should take care of it... I think.

Comment: Awesome Matt. That did the trick.  I really appreciate your help, hopefully this will help others as well.

Comment: @PurpleLagoon No problem! Don't forget to click the check mark below the number of votes for this answer, if you feel my answer is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87588/discussion-between-purple-lagoon-and-hopkins-matt).